# Create date column from quarter and year columns

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

Let's say I have the following columns in a dataframe.

```
temp = pd.DataFrame({'quarter': [1, 2, 1, 3, 4],
                   'year': [1994, 1995, 2001, 1997, 2014]})
```

How can I create a new 'date' column that represents the time with a datetime object? Let quarter 1 be Jan 1, quarter 2 be March 1, quarter 3 be June 1, and quarter 4 be Sept 1. For example, if it were quarter 1 in 1994, the 'date' column should have 1994-01-01.

Comment: Your expected quarters don't seem correct. Jan1, April1 July 1, October1. I.e. months (1, 4, 7, 10)

Comment: @ALollz What would you have expected the quarters to become?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62922662/10197418

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pd.to_datetime`:

```
pd.to_datetime(temp['year'].astype(str) + 'Q' + temp['quarter'].astype(str))
```

Output:

```
0   1994-01-01
1   1995-04-01
2   2001-01-01
3   1997-07-01
4   2014-10-01
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Is there a way to add a format like `, format='%YQ%m'`? I know it shouldn't be `%m`, but is there a way to do something like this?