# How do you convert a column containing year & quarter in a str format as '1947q1' to date format column where both year and quarter are considered?

Tags: python, python-3.x, date, datetime, string-to-datetime

```
  **Year_qtr GDP    ADJ_GDP**

2   1947q1  243.1   1934.5
3   1947q2  246.3   1932.3
4   1948q3  250.1   1930.3
5   1949q4  260.3   1960.7
```

Tried parse()  from dateutil package but didnt wwork.
Result dataframe should have 'Year_qtr' column as date values instead of object.

Comment: Is your data in a file or DataFrame?

Comment: The data is in a excel sheet and i have read the same into a dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pandas` already can do this out of the box! you can cast to datetime right away:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Year_qtr': ['1947q1', '1947q2', '1948q3', '1949q4']})

df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Year_qtr'])

# df
#   Year_qtr   datetime
# 0   1947q1 1947-01-01
# 1   1947q2 1947-04-01
# 2   1948q3 1948-07-01
# 3   1949q4 1949-10-01

# vice versa you can do
df['datetime'].dt.to_period("Q")
# 0    1947Q1
# 1    1947Q2
# 2    1948Q3
# 3    1949Q4
# Name: datetime, dtype: period[Q-DEC]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't store quarter in a datetime object. You can have them separately:

```
# Split year and quarter information
year, quarter = map(int, year_column.split('q'))
```

Comment: The thing is he is using a DataFrame.